# Google API failing CF9 failing for one address

Tags: google-maps

I am using the built in cfajax proxy in ColdFusion 9.0.1 cfmap. For one address it is failing. I am not sure why because when I go to the regular map API on Google it can be seen.
Here is the link.
http://www.renaudconsulting.net/map/capital-corner-shopping-center/hybrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps is different to the Maps API, and in particular the geocoder uses a *lot* more information to do its stuff. The API geocoder doesn't know about 6505 Annapolis Road; the Maps geocoder could be using that address to find a record of the shopping centre and other associated data. The API geocoder does know about "Annapolis Road, Landover Hills, MD, 20784".

Standard advice is not to use the client to geocode an address every time the page is viewed. Geocode the location yourself, store those coordinates, and use the coordinates to position a marker (retrieving them from the database in much the same way as you currently get your address).

Not only does doing that save Google's resources, it makes the map load more quickly and it protects you against changes in the geocoder -- it's not unknown for addresses which are successfully found one day not to work the next.

Comment: Hi Andrew that is very helpful, how would I geocode that location? I assume you are taking about latitude and longitude?

Comment: Geocoding is finding the lat/long of an address (the reverse, using lat/lng to find an address, is "reverse geocoding"). Use something like John Coryat's http://maps.huge.info/pinpointaddress.htm to get close to the right location and then drag the marker to get the correct coordinates. Other similar applications are available.